# Can not connect to my wifi

Tags: wireless

I can not connect to go online using Wi-fi. I have a dell vostro and I am NEW to Ubuntu. What drivers do I need? Would it be possible to get step by step instruction? currently I am connected by wire. Thank you in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: could you please type the following command into the command line and post the result for Network controller? `lspci | grep "Network"`

Comment: It would also be good to include which release (version) of Ubuntu are you using. The answer for 12.04 and earlier differs from 13.10 for example.

Answer (score 1):

**You will want to be connected to another means of accessing the internet such as Ethernet so you can download the required drivers.**

**If you are running 13.04 or 13.10:**
Open the dash and type 'drivers'. Click on 'software & updates'. The click the last tab to the right called 'additional drivers'. If your wireless card requires proprietary drivers that Ubuntu recognizes they may be listed here. If you have listings here select a driver and try it out.

If you don't have any drivers listed here. Return to the first tab,'Ubuntu Software', and be sure the 'Proprietary drivers' box is checked.

**If you are running 12.04:**

Open the dash and type 'drivers'. Click 'Additional Drivers' (also known as Jockey). You should see your Wireless Driver listed here. Select the recommended driver, and download/install.